# How to save and restore group of opened files in Delphi IDE?

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-xe3

For example I am working on some subtask of project, usually it is 3-7 files of sourcecode and i keep them opened in editor. When I finish and switch to another task, then I start to use another set of sourcecode files. 
But usually I have to switch to the task at least several times (when customers or testers change/clarify requirements, when some bugs are found etc). I would like to save set of opened in IDE files in order to be able to reopen them later.

Delphi desktops doesn't save opened files, only layout of forms, so it doesn't help.
Is there any way to do it? Maybe workaround ?

Comment: if you need to switch several times, then perhaps consider having 2 instances of the IDE open rather than having to close and re-open everytime you need to switch.

Comment: @Sams: It is impossible to open IDE for every task and keep it running.

Comment: Delphi does save open files. In DelphiXE2, check Tools - Options - Environment Options - Autosave Options - Editor files. Also, rather than open the files from within the IDE, you could pass the project-file to the IDE as a startup argument. You could make multiple windows shortcuts. No work around needed.

Comment: @Sam: I can't create many copies of project file for such task, because project can be changed any time by other developers (new conditionals, new paths, ...). But i accepted suggestion of David to make copies of DSK file as quite simple solution. Probably i will create small tool myself for fast switching between saved DSK files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delphi saves the desktop of open files in its .dsk file. This is associated with a Delphi project. So the obvious conclusion is that you just need to change projects. Make each sub-task be a branch in your version control system and that will allow you to operate on different Delphi projects for each sub-task.

If you don't want to do that, then I guess you could perform some trickery with .dsk files. Like this:

1. For each sub-task, open the set of files for that sub-task.
2. Then close the project and make a copy of the .dsk file. Name it like this: MyApp.dsk.subtask1. Do the same for all sub-tasks.
3. Whenever you need to switch sub-tasks, copy MyApp.dsk.subtaskN on top of MyApp.dsk before opening the project.

Obviously you could easily script that for convenience.

Comment: I had a hope that it is possible to do in IDE, but you are right, as workaround i can try to save DSK.